# Obtaining value from Calendar control without selecting a day

Tags: c#, wpf, calendar, wpf-controls

Is there a way (using a Calendar control in Visual Studio WPF) I can obtain a value without actually selecting a day within the control.

For example, I have a client that wants the calendar's DisplayMode = Year.
And now let's say they select the month of March within the control. That will change the DisplayMode to Month and no value is EVER set until they select a day in that month within the control.

Is there a way I can obtain the year and month and set it to a value without them actually selecting a day?  Because in this case the day does not matter.

I've found some workarounds that don't involve using the Calendar control or DatePicker but I would like to continue using these controls for UI purposes.

Comment: To clarify - only Calendar is used, not DatePicker?

Comment: Sorry yes, I am using the Calendar controller. @AaronThomas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to create a DisplayModeChanged event and change the mode accordingly:

```
private DateTime newdate = DateTime.Now;

private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   calctl.SelectedDate = DateTime.Now;
   calctl.DisplayMode = System.Windows.Controls.CalendarMode.Year;
}
private void calctl_DisplayModeChanged(object sender, CalendarModeChangedEventArgs e)
{
        if (calctl.DisplayMode == System.Windows.Controls.CalendarMode.Month)
        {
             newdate = calctl.DisplayDate;
             calctl.DisplayMode = System.Windows.Controls.CalendarMode.Year;
        }
}
```

This will allow you to change the month and/or year and not bother with the day. **You will want to set the initial display mode to month**.

Comment: I've already tried this before posting, but you cannot obtain a value out of this.  Yea you are providing a solution to the problem of advancing to the DisplayMode of month but you can't actually obtain any value from the SelectedDate if only the month is selected. For instance if I have just the month of March selected. I can't obtain any value if I did string theDate = calct1.SelectedItem.ToString(); because a day hasn't been selected.

Comment: Maybe if there is some way I could autoselect a day once the month has been chosen.  Any ideas?

Comment: I have changed the code so that you have a datetime variable called newdate that will always have the current selected month and year (since day is unimportant)

Comment: Note also be sure that the displaymode in the calendar properties is initially  set to month.